# Why is the symmetric matrix eigensolver in Eigen slower than Julia?

Tags: c++, julia, linear-algebra, eigen, eigenvalue

I was trying to profile Eigen's symmetric eigenvalue finder for a set of 512x512 matrices, and I found that it was much slower than Julia's LinearAlgebra library which was using dsyevr from openblas lapack under the hood. The code I used is

```
#define EIGEN_NO_DEBUG
#define EIGEN_USE_BLAS
#define EIGEN_USE_LAPACKE
// #define EIGEN_USE_MKL

#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <chrono>


using namespace std::chrono;
using namespace Eigen;

void compute_eigenvalues_symmetric(const MatrixXd & m) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    SelfAdjointEigenSolver<MatrixXd> eg;
    eg.compute(m);
    Eigen::VectorXd evals = eg.eigenvalues();
  }
}

int main() {

  int size = 512;
  MatrixXd test_matrix(size, size);
  test_matrix.setRandom();
  test_matrix = test_matrix * test_matrix.transpose();

  auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
  compute_eigenvalues_symmetric(test_matrix);
  auto end = high_resolution_clock::now();


  auto duration = duration_cast<seconds>(end - start);
  std::cout << "Time: " << duration.count() << " s" << std::endl;
}
```

compiled with `CMakeLists.txt`,

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "g++-11")

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
# set the project name
project(BLAS_TEST CXX)
enable_language(CXX)

# add the executable
set(CMAKE_C_COMILER gcc-11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "g++-11")


set(LAPACK_MANUAL "/opt/OpenBLAS/lib/libopenblas_haswellp-r0.3.17.dev.so")
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)

set(EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIRS "/path/to/my/.local/include")
include_directories(${EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(eigval_test eigval_test.cpp)
target_link_libraries (eigval_test ${LAPACK_MANUAL}) 
target_link_libraries(eigval_test Threads::Threads)

target_compile_options (eigval_test PRIVATE -O3 -march=native -pg)
```

I'm comparing the executable generated by this (modifying this to use the backend as MKL/Eigen/BLAS) to one generated by the following julia code

```
using LinearAlgebra

n = 512
X = rand(n, n)

X = X*X'

function eigval100(mat::AbstractArray)
    for i = 1:500
        a = eigvals(mat)
        println(i) 
    end
end

# to compile
eigval100(X)

@time eigval100(X)
```

My Julia code is using ~12 seconds, whereas my with MKL, Eigen uses ~24 seconds. whereas the standalone version uses ~35 seconds and the OpenBLAS version uses ~70 seconds on 1 thread. the profiler tells me that Eigen is using dsyev under the hood rather than the syevr as Julia does.

Is there anything extra I'm missing to make my Eigen code faster? My Eigen version is 3.4.0

Comment: Do you have control over the number of BLAS threads being used?

Comment: I use `EXPORT OMP_NUM_THREADS=1` which should set the threads for openblas according to the documentation. and my profiler tells me MKL and standalone Eigen are not using more than 1 thread with that variable set

Comment: For Julia you can check this with `LinearAlgebra.BLAS.get_num_threads()`, and set threads with `LinearAlgebra.BLAS.set_num_threads(N)`.

Comment: If you don't need the eigenvectors, try `eg.compute(m, EigenvaluesOnly);`

Comment: Thank you! that was what I was looking for, now it takes ~7 seconds with openblas